# How can I filter property of property of class in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have problem to filter an array of station aroundStreet 
I know about map but I need when choosen string is equal to around street return All info about MetroLine Class that contain line,intersection ,....

```swift
class Name{
    var farsiName:String
    var englishName:String

    init(farsi:String,english:String) {
        self.farsiName = farsi
        self.englishName = english
    }
}
class Station{
    var name:Name
    var isintersection:Bool
    var aroundStreet:[String]

    init(name:Name,aroundStreet:[String],isintersection:Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.aroundStreet = aroundStreet
        self.isintersection = isintersection

    }
}

class MetroLine{

    var name:(origin:Name,deste:Name)
    var lineNumber:Int
    var station:[Station]
    var intersection:[Name]
    var lineColor:UIColor

    var numberStations:Int{
        return station.count
    }

    init(name:(origin:Name,deste:Name),lineNumber:Int,station:[Station],intersection:[Name],lineColor:UIColor){

        self.lineNumber = lineNumber
        self.station = station
        self.intersection = intersection
        self.lineColor = lineColor
        self.name = name
    }

}
```

i try this code

```swift
var MetroBankArray = [MetroLine]()

func findUserLocation(origin:String)->Void{
        let new = MetroBankArray.map({$0.station.map({$0.aroundStreet.filter({$0 == origin})})})


    }
```

output

```
[[["nabard"]]]
```

Comment: Add the code you already tried.

Comment: It sounds as if you may have designed your model classes incorrectly but it's impossible to know. Unclear what you are trying to do. Give an example of actual input and desired output.

Comment: i try this  var MetroBankArray = [MetroLine]()
    
    func findUserLocation(origin:String)->Void{
        let new = MetroBankArray.map({$0.station.map({$0.aroundStreet.filter({$0 == origin})})})

        
    }

Comment: i don't know how filter nested class property?

Comment: Code edited ...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a search function to return the list of stations. Note that I changed station in stations for better readability.

```
class MetroLine {

var name:(origin:Name,deste:Name)
var lineNumber:Int
var stations:[Station]
var intersection:[Name]
var lineColor:UIColor

var numberStations:Int{
    return stations.count
}

init(name:(origin:Name,deste:Name),lineNumber:Int,stations:[Station],intersection:[Name],lineColor:UIColor){

    self.lineNumber = lineNumber
    self.stations = stations
    self.intersection = intersection
    self.lineColor = lineColor
    self.name = name
}

func searchStationAround(street: String) -> [Station] {  // All stations around
    var listOfStations =  [Station]()
    for station in stations where station.aroundStreet.contains(street) {
        listOfStations.append(station)
    }
    return listOfStations
  }
}
```

You could make it more robust by converting first all street names to lowercase…

Comment: this code not work error is Value of type 'MetroLine' has no member 'aroundStreet'

Comment: Don't understand the problem you get (unless you did not change station to stations as I did) ; Wrote it in playground and no error… aroundStreet is a station attribute, not a MetroLine ; so station.aroundStreet is [String]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to filter your inner array against the `origin` variable and then you need to check for what stations the inner filter returned anything by checking `count` on the result.

```
let filtered = MetroBankArray.filter { line in 
    line.station.filter { station in station.aroundStreet.contains(origin}.count > 0}
```

or to use the function you have

```
func findUserLocation(origin:String)->Void{
    let new = MetroBankArray.filter { line in 
        line.station.filter { station in station.aroundStreet.contains(origin}.count > 0}
    //...
}
```